# Javascript - Sort multiple objects in array and sort them by specific value

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to sort an array by the fastest times. The times comes from my database, which gives 2 different (double) numbers and a (String) name. In the below code I then combine the 2 times to have a combined time, which I put into the array along with the name as an object.

My problem is, I am unable to sort the array by the "time" part of the object I've made?

```
const divContainer = document.getElementById("container");
const url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/tourdefrance';

async function loadSortByTime(){
  const teamList = await fetch(url).then(response => response.json());
  const teamListLength = teamList.length;
  let timeArray = [];

  function time_convert(num){
    const hours = Math.floor(num / 60);
    const minutes = Math.round(num % 60);
    return hours + "t " + minutes + "'";
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < teamListLength; i++){
    const times = teamList[i];

    const combinedTime = (times.bjergtid + times.spurttid);
    const biker = [
      {
        name: times.name,
        time: time_convert(combinedTime)}
    ];

    console.log(timeArray);
    timeArray.push(biker);
    console.log(timeArray);
  }
  timeArray.sort((a,b) => (a.time > b.time) ? 1 : -1);

}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  loadSortByTime();
});
```

HTML code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sort By Time</title>
  <script src="../js/sortByTime.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're not assigning `combinedTime` to your `biker` objects.

Comment: I'm assigning a formatted version of it, isn't that still considered the combinedTime variable? Sorry if stupid question.

Comment: How important is fetch in this question? And why don't you show the original JSON? please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You are pushing strings into your `timeArray` not an **object** with `combinedTime`  property.  String doesn't have the property `combinedTime` so the language run time can't resolve it

Comment: @sinanspd thank you for explaining, I'm not very good with arrays, and realised I'd not actually done the thing I said I'd done. They should be objects now, but still doesn't sort by the "time" value

Comment: That is not an object. That's unary array containing one object. I recommend going through a basic javascript tutorial and patching the gaps in your knowledge regarding some of the structures in this language